# Running release version of Android Wear app throws RuntimeException due to ProGuard optimization

Tags: android, android-proguard

When running the release version of my Android Wear app, a `RuntimeException` is thrown when it is starting up. The message indicates that it is a `ProGuard` issue and gives a hint to the solution.

The question is how to translate this hint into a ProGuard rule?

Here is the error message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a required method for ambient support, likely due to proguard optimization. Please add com.google.android.wearable:wearable jar to the list of library jars for your project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the documentation of [WearableActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/activity/WearableActivity.html) you should add

```
dependencies {
     provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:1.0+'
 }
```

to your gradle file. Also add appropriate rules for proguard to proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.wearable.** {*;}
```

Comment: Thank you. The entry in the dependencies block was enough. I didn't need the proguard rule.